# Lightsaber blade "weight" in-universe

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

In-universe, a lightsaber is basically a controlled, fixed-length plasma stream that can be used as a sword. As such, the blade wouldn't have any mass (or infinitesimal mass if you want to get technical about E=mc<sup>2</sup>).

Anyone familiar with fencing or swordplay knows that the weight of the handle and blade, and thus the overall balance of the weapon, is critically important while fighting. A sword that is too blade-heavy is unwieldy; it is difficult to start, stop, and change the path of the blade as it's swung, which is vital to outmaneuvering your opponent in a duel. Conversely, a sword with too light a blade (equivalently, too heavy a hilt) is *too* easy to swing around. it's hard to "feel" where the blade is, and thus to make the minute changes needed to block a blow or land one. It can also be just as exhausting, in a different way, to wield such a sword; because most of the mass is behind your hand, it takes muscle power to point the blade forward instead of upward, while a balanced weapon would point directly forward from the user's hands. You also get no mechanical advantage while swinging it.

Obviously, out-of-universe the props were full "swords" that were then rotoscoped to paint the beam blade over the white wooden (later plastic) dowel that protruded from the saber. This gives the actual prop used by the actors a more realistic weight and balance, which can be seen in the duels (Darth Maul has to heave a bit to get that double-saber staff moving, and you can see the effort behind a full baseball swing of the sword by Luke or Vader in the original trilogy).

Was there any attempt in-universe to explain the weight and balance that an active lightsaber seemed to possess?

Comment: It was the Force!

Comment: Oh, so THAT's what that whole "Balance to the Force" thing was about!

Comment: Uggg.. +1 for the painful pun, DVK.

Comment: Plasma does indeed have mass, just like matter in a solid, liquid, gas, or Bose-Einstein condensate state.  You are perhaps thinking of photons, which do lack mass.

Comment: If you e.g. put a lead ring at the base of the blade (top of the hilt, technically), you can simulate the weight of a blade (while holding it from the handle). If you can assume the hand's position on the hilt; and you can add a mass to the end of the hilt that exerts the same lever force; then you can emulate a normal sword. Or, maybe simpler, Jedis are trained to deal with a weightless blade.

Comment: if the plasma is spinning in a magnetic field, the torque produced could create a gyroscopic force simulating weight as well

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There have been a few attempts (mostly in EU novels) to discuss the properties of the blade, but most analysis instead explains why Jedi (and Sith) could use the blade effectively *despite* the objections you correctly raise.

Here are the things we know:

The *weight* of a lightsaber is comparatively light, and the mass is entirely in the handle.  (We don't know the weight of the handles; they're thicker than a real sword hilt but hollow and filled with electronics. It's probably comparable to a heavy longsword hilt.)

The 'blade' is a magnetic 'bottle' containing the plasma generated by the lightsaber.  It generates a strong electromagnetic field.  This means that the blade will have a little resistance to motion when in the presence of ferrous metals (most of the time, in SW).  The blade will, therefore, 'bounce' off some metallic substances, even as it melts them.  (The duel in ESB has some good examples.)  The dense magnetic bottles are certainly the reason the blades 'bind' on each other rather than passing through each other.

(Note that when Jedi burn through bulkheads and doors, they always insert the lightsaber at right-angles, point first.  Clearly this is to avoid lateral resistance from the magnetic field.)

Apart from these magnetic effects, the blade is effectively weightless.

The basic handling, therefore, would be extremely hilt-heavy.  The natural balance point is probably all the way back *inside* the user's grip.

As you correctly point out, this would make the blade extremely hard to 'feel'.  This goes a long way to explain why only Jedi wield lightsabers.  (This also explains the usefulness of the training remotes; they cure the tendency to overcorrect the blade.  The first lesson Jedi are taught is to discard their physical senses and feel the blade position with the Force.  Clearly this is not just a teaching style but a practical necessity.)

Jedi must develop extremely strong wrists.  This is not a problem; like medieval knights, Jedi begin training at a very early age, including lightsaber training from day one.  Clearly this is, in part, to build wrist and arm muscle.  Note that Luke - who does not have this training - consistently uses his lightsaber two-handed at first.  He doesn't (and clearly can't) use it one-handed until he's gained much more experience and practice.

The heavy two-handed styles in common use in the original trilogy are clearly, therefore, a matter of *control*.  As with real longswords, the extra hand on the hilt provides control and direction, not power.  (Lucas directed the actors in the original trilogy to behave as if the blades were extremely heavy... hence the kendo-like styles.  This makes sense; an old man and a wounded cyborg would no longer have their youthful wrist strength and control, and would have to be cautious.)

These drawbacks conceal advantages in disguise.  Sure, they're a problem in a swordfight.  But Jedi aren't primarily duellists, they're police.  Their 'typical opponent' is a room full of people with blasters.  The blade-light overcorrection that harms 'feel' in the bind also gives you rapid tip movement to stop a flying blaster bolt - if you have a Force sense telling you where the tip *should* go.

(Note that Sith, who typically *do* expect other swordsmen as enemies, frequently seem to wipe the floor with Jedi in a straight swordfight.  Compare Dooku's tight, defensive style - and note the curved hilt of his lightsaber, letting him keep the blade forward without pronation of the wrist.  Likewise, Maul's staff-style avoids the whole 'feel' problem, at the cost of reach - and an intense danger of cutting off his own leg.)

This is why non-force users don't wield lightsabers - without the precise Force sense of blade location and combat movement, they're likely to overcorrect and hurt themselves.  And without the intense training, they wouldn't have the strength and stamina to control it.
(This is canon; note that in the EU, Talon Karrde considers the lightsaber at Luke's belt to be proof of his identity *by itself*.  "You were either Luke Skywalker, Jedi, or else someone with a taste for antiques and an insufferably high opinion of his swordsmanship."  Clearly, without Force training it's *not possible* to develop sufficient control to use the saber effectively.)

Comment: great analysis.

Comment: 'strong wrists'...they don't marry...ew

Comment: Adding insult to injury, people who experimented with lightsabers and made even a single mistake could possibly maim or kill themselves. As a martial artist with weapons training, I can tell you, learning to use weapons can be a painful experience. With a lightsaber your first training error might be your last.

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze: I don't know if it's movie canon, but it is obvious there have to be training lightsabers.

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze: It's established in the EU at least that those lightsabers the children are using are training weapons emitting coloured lights and an unpleasant electric shock rather than anything lethal.

Comment: I don't buy the fact that lightness makes it hard to control, most people can put a laser pointer exactly where they want it on a white board with a few seconds of practice.  A fencing foil is hilt heavy and easy to control.  frankly, the lightsabers should have been used one handed.  After all, real sabers ARE one handed cutting swords, and lightsabers are very light.  And even a not-weightless two pound european saber from the 18 century was driven almost entirely from the wrist, not the arm.

Comment: Added to that, invocation of force powers seems to need a free hand to gesture, meaning not only is there no reason to wield a lightsaber two handed, there is a damn good reason not to.  Imagine a jedi fighting one handed in the style of european rapier while using his off hand to throw 'force punches' or 'force blocks'.  A force based 'main gauche'.

Comment: @Thaddeus In many books, especially Jedi Apprentice and Junior Jedi Knight series books, there are multiple references to how most (full/real) lightsabers have a lower "stun" setting. This probably weakens the plasma to basically cause a severe cigarette-type burn on contact, but not enough to sever limbs or melt/cut through durasteel.

Comment: Have you got any source for the assertion that lightsabers have magnetic fields that (a) cause them to bound off metal and (b) are *clearly* [citation needed] the reason you stick a lightsaber into something point-first?

Comment: @Rawling - all you have to do is watch "The Mask of Zorro". The pointy end goes into the other man.

Comment: @Rawling Yes.  The original ESB film crew spent a lot of time discussing what lightsabers bounced off or cut through and why.  If you watch the final duel, it's clear that lightsabers bounce off metal (while they damage it).  And yes, given basic magnetic field physics that makes it obvious why you'd cut through ferromagnetic doors point first.  @Omegacron; he's referring to my assertion about door-cutting, not general lightsaber combat.

Comment: So... no source?

Comment: @Rawling: Been trying to remember where I saw the interview on lightsaber physics of ESB, but it was many years ago... sorry.  For a source on why a dense magnetic plasma bottle would behave that way, consult any physics textbook.

Comment: @Tynam Ehe, fair enough.

Comment: @Tynam - um...no.  Any bottle that encloses the plasma would have to close off the tip too or it would shoot out like a blaster...just like the edges.  If metal interferes with the field, it would do the same for the sides as the point.

Comment: @Oldcat: It's not about metal interfering with the field.  (You *want* plasma to shoot out the point; that's melting the door.)  It's about *movement* in metal - try to move a dense magnetic field laterally across metal, and the counter-current is going to make your life difficult.  You don't get that problem going point-first.

Comment: " Clearly, without Force training it's not possible to develop sufficient control to use the saber effectively." - What about General Grievous? He uses four at once, and (as far as I am aware) has no force abilities.

Comment: @DrRDizzle: He controls four lightsabers in *cyborg arms*.  It's easy to get the positioning right when your wrists are servomotors that can automatically tilt in the exact same way every time, and don't tire.

Comment: I would love to see this answer updated for the Disney canon introduced in *The Force Awakens*. Don't forget to use spoiler tags!

Comment: @lunchmeat317: I'm not sure that's necessary; I didn't see any changes that affect the answer.  (PM me if you think otherwise; I'm avoiding putting spoilers in comments!)

Comment: At the risk of having to duck, what do you think about Finn and Rey? They weren't exactly masterly, but they were both far from bumbling oafs with a lightsaber - especially considering that this was the first time using one for both of them. And neither had Force training.

Comment: @MishaRosnach Finn has melee weapons training, probably including fighting *against* lightsabers.  He's still clumsy and over-aggressive, using violence instead of skill, and Kylo is pretty obviously toying with him.  Rey, on the other hand, was already an expert with a melee weapon (which *really* helps), and had already read Kylo's mind with sheer Force talent - so clearly she has enough Force ability to pick up the basics by sheer feel.

Answer (score 16):

The very issues you mention are part of why they were traditionally the weapons of Jedi alone.  Other variations existed, in forms closer to pikes and naginata, but using one as a sword gave the user tremendous flexibility. The trade-off is that it requires tremendous skill to use a lightsaber.  Partially due to the weightlessness of the blade, but also due to the inherent gyroscopic tendency of the looping plasma. Much like the physics demonstration where a user pushes on a spinning wheel and it moves at an angle where the user attempts to push it to, so too does a lightsaber not move in the way you would intuitively assume.

From [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lightsaber):

> Due to the weightlessness of plasma and the strong gyroscopic effect generated by it, lightsabers required a great deal of strength and dexterity to wield, and it was extremely difficult—and dangerous—for the untrained to attempt using. However, in the hands of an expert of the Force, the lightsaber was a weapon to be greatly respected and feared. To wield a lightsaber was to demonstrate incredible skill and confidence, as well as masterful dexterity and attunement to the Force.

In general though, the physics you see that appear to be from the blade possessing weight are actually from the gyroscopic effect the looping plasma causes.  In real life, looping plasma wouldn't do that (at least not on that noticeable of a scale), but this is Star Wars. :)

Comment: Then how could Luke pick it up so easily? He's swinging it around very naturally within just a few total minutes of holding the thing while it's on, and he only had maybe a couple hours max of time spent under Obi-Wan's tutelage with it. Even Han is able to use it effectively as a cutting tool, while exhausted and half-frozen no less.

Comment: Honestly?  'cause they didn't think about the physics too much when doing the movies.  (Look at the question about the MF banking when turning, for example.)  They later backfilled the idea of it requiring Jedi Strength and Agility... but that was mostly done via the Expanded Universe -- in Lucas' original script, they were 'Laser Swords' and he really didn't work out how the sword play would work.  There's a massive difference between using a carving knife, and swinging a sword, though -- crude use isn't too hard.. But expert use requires extensive training.

Comment: Another way to say it... It's TERRIBLY hard to use one.. The Jedi are just THAT good, and make it look easy.  And Han, being the universal stud, is stronger than he looks.

Comment: Those tykes didn't seem to be having any trouble.

Comment: @Oldcat -- Those were also training sabers; possibly FAR easier to use.  I'm not terribly sure HOW you would render a plasma stream down to an almost harmless level.. but apparently it makes them more like sticks :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe in EU retconning.  They said those were sabers in the movie, so they were sabers.  Normally, training weapons are heavier and harder to use than normal, to help you build strength.

Comment: If the blade is "weightless" is has zero "gyroscopic effect". Unless its inertial mass and gravitational mass are different as in a Banksian [Lazy Gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Against_a_Dark_Background#Lazy_Guns) ...

Answer (score 1):

The blade of the lightsaber is controlled by a...gyroscopic...effect. This term is probably not a perfect explanation, but it is the closest thing to our own science that fits. The hilt emits a beam of plasma with such infinitesimal mass that it should be weightless, and it would on its own. However the blade is contained as an elliptical continuation, or perhaps a parabolic arc that exits and returns to the hilt. This is made possible by an electromagnetic containment field (aka forcefield) which forces it to continue its cycle as it is emitted, then bent at the tip of the field, and then returned to the hilt. The gyroscopic effect comes into play because of the fact that the rate at which it is exiting and returning to the hilt causes a very powerful pull which simulates the feeling of "weight" in the blade. However instead of just pulling the entire hilt away from you, the pull is held in place by the containment field, sort of like how a wheel's edges want to continue turning even if the center stops moving. Thus with this simulated weight it acts basically the same as a perfectly balanced sword.

Of course this is all conjecture based on canon literature which has now sadly been de-legitimized by the release of the newest movie. It is however still very fun to think about, and provides the most plausible explanation for the implausible weapon.