# What property causes lightsabers to not cut through other lightsabers during combat?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

I know there are materials in the universe (both in the StarWars universe, and other plausible materials outside the StarWars universe) which cannot be penetrated by a lightsaber, but I'm not familiar with what properties of the lightsabers themselves cause them to collide on impact rather than pass through?

Aren't lightsabers just controlled beams of energy? (I'm assuming the answer here is no, considering the question).

Comment: Presumably the intensity of the energy contained in a light sabre beam is enough that a similar beam cannot penetrate it. Basically the same reason a regular sword/knife can’t cut through another sword/knife: their density and hardness are at the same level.

Comment: From [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/8855): ​ "The 'blade' is a magnetic 'bottle' containing the plasma generated by the lightsaber. It generates a strong electromagnetic field. This means that the blade will have a little resistance to motion when in the presence of ferrous metals (most of the time, in SW). The blade will, therefore, 'bounce' off some metallic substances, even as it melts them. (The duel in ESB has some good examples.) The dense magnetic bottles are certainly the reason the blades 'bind' on each other rather than passing through each other." ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Continued from the same answer: ​ "(Note that when Jedi burn through bulkheads and doors, they always insert the lightsaber at right-angles, point first. Clearly this is to avoid lateral resistance from the magnetic field.)" ​ ​ ​ ​