# Will Ezra's lightsaber revolutionize dueling?

Tags: star-wars, weapon, lightsaber, star-wars-rebels

Ezra's lightsaber (pictued below) features a gun attachment that can be single-handedly fired while the lightsaber is activated. The energy bolt cannot be deflected back at the firer.

Regarding the lightsaber his Jedi Master, Kanan, flippantly said "Well, it's…different, but that seems about right for you. Come on" [(Star Wars Rebels: Path of the Jedi)](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ezra's_lightsaber)

[image]

I believe that he has overlooked the greatest advancement in lightsaber technology in millenia. Should the opponent be forced to block the blade with his own lightsaber, the gun becomes nigh impossible to evade.

Here are some pictures to illustrate my point (complete with bad drawings and sound effects):

**Exhibit: How Ezra's lightsaber could have saved the Old Republic**

*Exhibit A: It could have saved Mace Windu*
[image]

*Exhibit B: It could've helped Yoda defeat Sidious*
[image]

Comment: Are you aware that Ezra has had his ass comprehensively kicked by every other duellist that he's come into contact with?

Comment: +1 for the quality of your elite Photoshop skills

Comment: Well he hasn't used it this way yet :) Thanks Peter, I try.

Comment: Given the fact that Rebels takes place before A New Hope and by The Force Awakens gunless lightsabers are still used, it seems the answer is no, it didn't revolutionize lightsaber duels.

Comment: Awfully tempted to VTC as speculation based.

Comment: @Peter The mad photoshop skills secured my +1 as well :)

Comment: @Peter But -1 for lack of freehand circles.

Comment: +1 for the sound effects. Including "Pew! Pew!" improves many things, young padawan.

Comment: A better question is why don't Jedi simply carry a small stunner in addition to their light saber.  It would allow them to disable their opponent without needing to carve them up or deflect lethal laser blasts into them.

Comment: Your "pew pew"'s are without doubt, the highlight of my day so far.

Comment: This is why my Sith costume includes a blaster AND lightsaber. Sith don't care about rules... just victory.

Comment: It's usefulness only lies in being able to have both a lightsaber and a blaster without carrying two items. I've never seen any example when the two modes were used simultaneously.

Comment: Everything pales in comparison to the elegance that is the [Jedi-Killer](http://i.imgur.com/RpkTNLc.jpg)

Comment: Also keep in mind that Jedi Masters were a stubborn bunch. No self-respecting Jedi Master would be caught dead using a blaster, unless it was an absolute last resort (ex. Kenobi's fight with Grievous).

Comment: These pictures show scenarios where it would have helped, but because it wasn't present in these actual scenes, it's hard to say the actual effect it would have had. I imagine had the bag guys known that the other had a blaster/sabre combo, they wouldn't have put themselves in the position in the first place to get shot.

Comment: How is the question opinion based? There's solid evidence that this was a unique and revolutionary design, but that it did not change lightsaber combat long-term. Reasons as to why it didn't might be speculative, but at it's core the question has a very apparent and provable answer.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

No. According to [Star Wars Insider #154](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Insider_154), you need to disengage the blade in order for the battery pack to power the blaster. Your lightsaber duel would last about four seconds and then you'd get your hands cut off.

[image]

If anything, Ezra's revolutionary design would make it more likely that you'd get killed in record time which is why this style of fighting is known as Form 8; ***Dumbasso***

Comment: "where he **can** disengage his saber". it does not say he *must* disengage for the blaster to work.

Comment: I believe every instance we've seen of the blastsaber has the blade disengaging when being fired. I think you are also misreading that sentence. The "can" relates to the option to use the multi-function, wherein the blade is disengaged and the blaster enabled.

Comment: Although, the stun blaster does give Ezra (and Kanan, who has wielded this lightsaber on occasions) something to do while they close the gap to their opponent.

Comment: What's a *mutli function*?

Comment: @Bergi Aside from being a typo, it's a polite way to call it a multi tool.  Luke gave us the sci fi sword.  Ezra gave us the sci fi swiss army knife.

Comment: I'm almost positive I've seen Kanan fire the blaster while the lightsaber was engaged, and Ezra was surprised because he "never thought of using it like that".  I'll try to dig up the specific scene later.

Comment: The image says his lightsaber is light and quick, but the addition of the blaster would appear to make the handle unbalanced and heavier than normal.

Comment: Bah! Why does it need power? Just fit one of these to it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mIK7CujSrQ
It would probably be pretty good for distracting your enemy in the face mid-dual and is smaller than the blaster.

Comment: @Murphy - Hey, I've had a great idea. I'll strap an explosive to the side of my lightsaber. I can't see anyone using that against me in combat.

Comment: @Richard You've already got a battery pack which is pretty much a big blob of potentially explosive energy.

Comment: @Murphy - Slug throwers? How inelegant.

Comment: @Xantec It also makes its form closer to that of an actual saber.

Comment: @Axelrod http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8850/lightsaber-blade-weight-in-universe

Comment: @Xantec In the OT, lightsabers were meant to feel heavy and hard to move when activated. Thus Luke swinging like a baseball player.

Comment: Hand-drawn circles get an automatic +1.

Comment: I'm frankly surprised to see such condescension in a post from @Valorum...

Comment: @T.J.L. - If you can suggest a better name for the form, I'm open to suggestions; "Suicidio", perhaps?

Answer (score 28):

Ezra's lightsaber's design would have changed the rules of lightsaber combat, but not enough to save the Old Republic. Your idea, however, is potentially enough to save the Old Republic.

There is a major difference between Ezra's lightsaber and your idea. Like Richard stated, Ezra's weapon cannot draw the blade and fire **simultaneously**.

Ezra's lightsaber was able to significantly influence the tactical circumstances of battle, however. In the finale to Season 1, Kanan borrowed Ezra's lightsaber to fight with the Grand Inquisitor. Kanan had the sense to mix shooting and swordfighting, which was enough to surprise the Grand Inquisitor and grant a measure of tactical advantage. Ezra's reaction to Kanan's strategy was simply one of surprise and "why didn't I think of that?"

Ezra never intended for his lightsaber to do both at the same time. It just didn't come to mind. When he built his lightsaber, what drove his design decisions is the need to not get caught by Imperial spot checks. Therefore, he had the illegal lightsaber doubled as a legal stun pistol to evade detection, and to ensure he is not helpless in battle when revealing his Jedi identity is not an option.

The idea of shooting *during* swordfighting, however, is a very good one nonetheless (though Ezra can't claim most of the credit):

- As the Clone Wars and the Great Jedi Massacre demonstrated, Jedi are vulnerable to shots they can't block, such as during a saber lock.
- A traditional lightsaber has three Kyber crystals: The main energy focusing crystal, and two secondary crystals that allow the wielder to configure the blade's length and power
- If you can reduce the power output of a blade, theoretically you can also divert part of the power into shooting without sheathing the blade.
- It can be a low powered stun, or maybe even shoot to kill. Who knows?

Basically, it seems the theory is sound that a lightsaber that can swordfight and shoot simultaneously is feasible. That said, the question then comes down to: If a lightsaber's shot is incapable of killing, then would a stun blast be significant against a Sith Lord, a master of pain? A comic I chanced upon a month back showed a pre-Phantom Menace Darth Maul being attacked by a Nightsister with Force Lightning - and the Nightsister implying that only the Sith Lords can endure and resist such an attack.

Comment: Hmm.  You've got an interesting point about "would a stun blast be significant against…a master of pain?".

Answer (score 10):

I don't think it would make much of a difference. Especially if it became widespread and it wasn't a surprise. Look at that picture of Windu. *He is using the force to catch a lightning storm with his blade.* What do you think would happen if there was a couple blaster bolts added into that malestrom?

Judging by what happens when Vader get shot in ESB, Not too much.

[image]

It would just be something they'd have to adapt to.

Comment: Just a minor comment, Palpatine is *casting* a Lightning storm from his hands. It's *Mace Windu* who is catching it, and then on his Lightsaber.

Comment: Catching on his saber, and deflecting.  That's why Palpatine is getting deformed.

Comment: Right concept, wrong movie and person. In the beginning of TFA, Kylo Ren stops a blaster/lightning bolt with the Force that was fired by Poe Dameron. In the scene above I don't think Vader is using the Force at all. Remember, his arm is metal. I think he just blocks the blaster bolt ([note the sparks and smoke that result](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHH6YVHGh90))

Comment: Darth Vader didn't use the Force. In Legends at least, his artificial hands are made of a very strong and durable metal, which is attributed to as the reason he could block and absorb Han's shots with negligible damage to his bare hands.